# Can I check which section a string came from in an array?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

If I have an array like

```
Dim list As String()
```

and list is read from a file with

```
list = Split("filehere.txt", ",")
```

and I use something like

```
If list.Contains("string") then
code here
End If
```

can I find out which string of the array "string" came from, for example: string(0) or string(16)

Answer (score 5):

In .NET, to find the location of an object in a list you can use [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx).

The method will return -1 if the object is not found. This allows you to use the same metod to check if the list contains the object and where it is.